# Python numpy matrix multiplication mismatch in core dimension

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, numeric

I am trying to matrix multiply a 2x2 matrix with a 2x1 matrix. Both matrices have entries which are linspaces such that the resulting 2x1 matrix gives me a value for each value of the linspace.

I get this dimensionality error however.

> matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 1 is different from 2)

For readability I am not posting the whole code but what's necessary.

I have also replaced linspace values with indicative text.

Matrix "L" is a result of other 2x2 multiplications which contain constants, thus no errors there.

The matrix B (2x2) gives the desired result, so the problem comes down to the multiplication between B and C.

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *

# Defining range of values
z = np.linspace(initial, final, 10)
g = np.linspace(initial, final, 10)
y = np.linspace(initial, final, 10)

# Matrix operations
A = np.array([[1, z], [0, 1]], dtype=object)
B = np.matmul(L,A)
C = np.array([[y],[g]])

D = np.matmul(B, C)

print(total)
```

An alternative POV of what I am trying to do, is that for the matrix "B" when multiplied with the 2x1 "C" which contains unknowns, to calculate those unknowns "y" and "g"

Many thanks,

P.S; For an array "C" with single value entries, the multiplication runs as expected.

Edit; As per mozway's suggestion, I am providing the prints of array "A" and "M" which will make stuff clearer, but let M =  B

[image]

Comment: Why the `sympy` import?

Comment: Used sympy for some preliminary symbolic calculations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [66]: initial, final = 0,1
In [67]: z = np.linspace(initial,final,11)
In [68]: z
Out[68]: array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ])
```

`A` is (2,2), but contains a mix of array and scalars

```
In [69]: A = np.array([[1,z],[0,1]], object)
In [70]: A
Out[70]: 
array([[1,
        array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ])],
       [0, 1]], dtype=object)
In [71]: A.shape
Out[71]: (2, 2)
```

Now make a (2,2) numeric array:

```
In [72]: L = np.eye(2)
In [75]: L[1,1] = 2
In [76]: np.matmul(L,A)
Out[76]: 
array([[1.0,
        array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ])],
       [0.0, array([2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.])]],
      dtype=object)
```

`matmul` does work with object dtype arrays, provided the elements implement the necessary `+` and `*`.  The result is still (2,2), but the (1,1) term `2*z`.

Now for the `C`:

```
In [77]: C = np.array([[z],[z]])
In [78]: C
Out[78]: 
array([[[0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ]],

       [[0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ]]])
In [79]: C.shape
Out[79]: (2, 1, 11)
```

This is float dtype, 3d array.

```
In [81]: B=Out[76]
In [82]: np.matmul(B,C)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-82-5eababb7341e>", line 1, in <module>
    np.matmul(B,C)
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 1 is different from 2)

In [83]: B.shape
Out[83]: (2, 2)
In [84]: C.shape
Out[84]: (2, 1, 11)
```

There's a mismatch in shapes.  But change `C` definition so it is a 2d array:

```
In [85]: C = np.array([z,z])
In [86]: C.shape
Out[86]: (2, 11)
In [87]: np.matmul(B,C)
Out[87]: 
array([[array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
        array([0.1 , 0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.2 ]),
 ...
        array([1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8]),
        array([2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.])]],
      dtype=object)
In [88]: _.shape
Out[88]: (2, 11)
```

Here the (2,2) `B` matmuls with (2,11) just fine producing (2,11).  But each element is itself a (11,) array - because of the `z` used in defining `A`.

But you say you want a (2,1) `C`.  To get that we have to use:

```
In [91]: C = np.empty((2,1), object)
In [93]: C[:,0]=[z,z]
In [94]: C
Out[94]: 
array([[array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ])],
       [array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ])]],
      dtype=object)
```

Be very careful when trying to create `object` dtype arrays.  Things might not be what you expect.

Now matmul of (2,2) with (2,1) => (2,1), object dtype

```
In [95]: D = np.matmul(B,C)
In [96]: D.shape
Out[96]: (2, 1)
In [99]: D
Out[99]: 
array([[array([0.  , 0.11, 0.24, 0.39, 0.56, 0.75, 0.96, 1.19, 1.44, 1.71, 2.  ])],
       [array([0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. , 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2. ])]],
      dtype=object)
```

Keep in mind that `matmul` is very fast with working with numeric dtype arrays.  It does work with object dtype arrays, but speed is much slower, more like using list comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do (you should provide a reproducible example, there are currently many missing variables), and the expected output.

Nevertheless, the definition of `A` is fundamentally wrong. I imagine you expect a 2x2 array, but as `z` is a `(10,)` shaped array, you will end up with A being a weird object array whose element (0,1) is an array.

This prevents you do to any further mathematical operation.